# Merge two databases with identical structure and Hibernate mappings

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Following situations:

I got two databases featuring an identical structure. On top of each of these databases runs an instance of the same app using Hibernate for ORM. The two are completely independent.

Now I have to merge both applications into one. In some tables, adjustments need to be made to avoid violating unique key constraints.

Since both databases are identical in terms of structure and the same Hibernate mapping is used, is there a way to use Hibernate for the task? I'm thinking of loading an Object from database A, modifying it in code and simply saving it to a Session from a SessionFactory based on database B. I'm wondering whether Hibernate would be able to update the primary and foreign key values accordingly and how difficult it would be to handle dependencies to objects that are not copied from the database A (because they are not needed any more).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

isn't it easier to just do a database dump from database A and import it into database B? Or as an alternative use `insert into B.table (col1,col2) values (select col1,col3 from A.table)` ?

Comment: This is not possible since unique key contraints exist. Some entries also have to be merged into one while others will remain separate.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are MySQL, you use the MERGE storage engine. Here are the steps:

-In one of your databases, update all your id via Hibernate using the cascade all. All your id have to be increment by the last id of your other database on each table:

User1 (2000 rows, lastId: 2000) and User2 (3000 rows, lastId: 3000) -> User1 (2000 rows, lastId: 2000) and User2 (3000 rows, firstId:3000, lastId: 6000)

-Create an other database that merge all your databases

-Extract a dump from your new database and load this dump in your final database -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html

This is one possible way :)

Comment: This is not possible since unique key contraints exist. Some entries also have to be merged into one while others will remain separate. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread, but I had a similar problem.

I solved including two date fields : `included_date` and `changed_date` to my tables, and also, I included another field to save the date I last sync the databases somewhere else (I have a table with configuration info).

When my system connects to the server I send the date from the last sync, then my routine can compare which rows hava been included or changed since my last sync.

Every new row I set the date into the `included_date` field, so when I sync I know which rows were created after my last sync, then I can do an `INSERT`. The same happens with row changes and the `changed_date` field, then I do an `UPDATE`.